# How to create mfra box for ismv file if it is not present?

Tags: live-streaming, mpeg-4

I am working on Live Smooth Streaming and it creates ismv file.

I want to copy this ismv file to other location.

But as streaming is in progress so copied file is corrupted.

I tested this file using Mp4Explorer and compared with other ismv files.

I found that copied ismv file lacks mfra atom.

Please suggest how to add mfra atom for ismv file so that copied ismv file can be easily played?

Comment: I found one concept to append 'mfra' box. IIS uses SSFMuxAddStream to add 'mfra' box to the live streaming file. Please suggest if it can be done using code.

Comment: Please explain mfra creation logic for appending in ismv.

Answer (score 1):

If you're live streaming I would not expect the Movie Fragment Random Access (mfra) box to be present. I believe it is used only used server side to allow for easy fragment extraction and is never passed across to the player. You'll also see the mfra in any mp4 files you have on your local disk.

What you are likely capturing is the individual fragments of the stream. These are made from the Movie Fragment (moof) and Media data (mdat). The moof has two other atoms inside, Movie Fragment Header (mfhd) and the Track Fragment (traf).

If you are trying to reassemble the file from fragments you will need to do this (conceptually)

```
[ftyp][moov][fragment][fragment]...[fragment][mfra]
```

Where each [] is a box that may contain other boxes. See [Alex Zambelli's blog](http://alexzambelli.com/blog/2009/02/10/smooth-streaming-architecture/) for some good info. You will need to create the `[ftyp][moov]` and the `[mfra]` to properly represent all of your other fragments.